# wireslessproxd flooding my system log

Tags: macos, logging, console, macos-highsierra

Due to a disk problem i ended up in `system.log` today, only to find that about every 2-3 seconds the following information gets dumped into the log:

```
default 10:51:07.210542 +0200   wirelessproxd   Stop advertising for process sharingd (365) of type 16
default 10:51:07.210626 +0200   wirelessproxd   Nothing left to advertise, stopping
default 10:51:07.210861 +0200   wirelessproxd   Start advertising for process sharingd (365) of type 16 with advertising interval 432 (270.00 ms)
default 10:51:07.210933 +0200   wirelessproxd   advertisingRulesOSX - advertisements: (
    {
        kCBAdvAppleMfgTypeKey = 16;
        kCBAdvDataAppleMfgData = <07ff4c00 10020b00>;
        kCBAdvOptionUseFGInterval = 0;
    }
)
default 10:51:07.211104 +0200   wirelessproxd   Requesting to start 
advertising for clients 16  with (
    {
        kCBAdditionalAppleMfgAdvertisements =         ();
        kCBAdvDataAppleMfgData = <07ff4c00 10020b00>;
        kCBAdvOptionUseFGInterval = 0;
        kCBMsgArgIsPrivilegedDaemon = 1;
    }
)
default 10:51:07.229012 +0200   wirelessproxd   Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
```

My system has been behaving a little bit strange lately. I never had similar problems before. I'm running **High Sierra 10.13.5**.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: `wirelessproxd` handles AirDrop communication too by the way, and so if you're seeing tons of messages from it you likely have other devices communicating over AWDL in the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wirelessproxd is the Wireless Proxy Daemon. It’s a service that handles certain networking functions.

"Advertising" means broadcasting a machine’s network identity so that other machines can find it. For instance, functions like AirDrop and handoff with your iPhone won’t work if your computer can’t be found. This function is essential for your wireless network
to function correctly.

The following `apple.stackexchange` post might offer some help :
[How to disable logging to system.log in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157154/how-to-disable-logging-to-system-log-in-os-x)